# ExpressJS - How to jump to the next middleware which has initial url defined

Tags: javascript, express, backend, middleware

Example code:

```
app.use('/list-product', (req, res, next) => {
  // Do stuff
  next();
})

app.use('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("I'm here")
})
```

Somehow it doesn't log "I'm here'", which means `next()` call doesn't work.

But if I change `'/add-product'` to `'/'` or I remove it at all, it works. Why is that?

How can I jump to the next middleware which has initial url on it as the example above?

Comment: What URL does it not log "I'm here" for?  Are you  100% sure that this is the order of your two middleware handlers?

Comment: Yes my bad, Edited

Comment: Now you've modified it and those are two separate middlewares that don't match the same URL.  You should never get both of them firing for the same URL.  I don't understand what request URL causes what problem.  `next()` causes the next middleware that matches the current URL to run.  It doesn't just go to the next middleware regardless of URL match.

Comment: As I understand it, these two middlewares wouldn't be on the same middleware chain as the request is quite different for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't quite understand that when you put a path in front of the middleware, the URL must a least be a partial match for that path for that middleware to be called at all.

So, when you do a request for `/list-product`, that will match your `/list-product` middleware which will then call `next()`.  That will continue on the middleware chain looking for other middleware handlers that match the `/list-product` path.  When it gets to your next middleware for `/add-product`, that doesn't match `/list-product` so it is skipped (not called).

If you change `app.use('/add-product', ...)` to `app.use('/', ...)` or to `app.use(...)` with no path, then those last two are matches for `/list-product` so they will get called.  The `/` middleware is a partial match (for all URLs) and middleware with no path will be called for all URLs.  `app.use()` runs for partial matches.  The more specific request handlers like `app.get()` and `app.post()` require a more complete match.